# How to get all groups a users is member of in Active Directory, in PHP (connecting to LDAP directory)

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I have a website which can check if a user is member a of a specific group in Active Directory. Now I want to echo all groups which a user is a member of. I can't find any examples of this in the internet, and I don't know where to start. Any help is appreciated.
Please take in mind that I'm not a professional programmer/webdesigner.

I'm checking on the users sAMAccountname.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check **[memberOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677099%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** multivalued attribute.

It contains full DN of group.

This question has already been answered here: [PHP LDAP Get user details of member which is a member of a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327104/php-ldap-get-user-details-of-member-which-is-a-member-of-a-group?rq=1)

Comment: Hi, I followed your link, and I'm actually using parts of that script to get user details from users within a specified group. Now what I'm searching for is just the other way around; I want to get a list of all groups from a specific user.

Comment: I have to make an apology. I could edit the script in a way it worked for me. Thanks for you help. My question is answered.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by:

- Look up the user, read memberOf attributes
- Active Directory use recursive groups, you need to look up these at the client side
- Active Directory has a default limit of 1000 results returned, so you need to use [paged results](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-control-paged-result.php) to be sure you get all groups (requires PHP 5.4)

For speed, you should utilize OR filter for the recursive lookup like so: (|(memberOf=group1)(memberOf=group2)) for the recursive lookup + only look up a group once, so requests to the server is minimized.

Answer (score 0):

I came over several answers that recommend `memberOf`. Note, that this is only a good solution for testing for direct group membership. This would require a recursive and somewhat slow lookup.

If you are using ActiveDirectory, and you like to test for indirect group membership, than `tokenGroups` is the attribute you need to read. Note that the groups are returned as binary value (SID). These SIDs can be compared to a group's `objectsid`. Find PHP sample code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73430227/336311